# Why SqlAchemy create_engine ECHO flag TRUE doesn't prevent SQL statement to get in the logs?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking for a simple way to occasionally prevent SQLAlchemy to include SQL statements into the error logs (it could contain sensitive data).

I have came across with ECHO flag for the create_engine function which based on the documentation should do the trick. [DOC](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo)

But it doesn't. Based on my test the error message still contains the SQL statement

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "my_table" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM my_table;
                      ^

[SQL: SELECT * FROM my_table;]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

The test script was simple, here is the gist of it (echo set to false):

```
raw_sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table;"

# get session
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI, echo=False)
connection = engine.connect()
session_maker = sessionmaker()
session = session_maker(bind=connection)

# execute
session.execute(text(raw_sql))
```

Comment: It emits the message because of the error; if you queried a table that actually exists then you would get no output. If you're concerned about leaking _data_ you might want to set the engine's `hide_parameters` flag to `True`.